# How to read the session info in ServiceStack

Tags: session, servicestack

How can I read the session info in ServiceStack?

```
    public class HelloService : Service
    {
          public object Any(Hello request)
          {
               // How can I pull the session info i.e. UserId here?
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to your typed custom session with:

```
public object Any(Hello request)
{
    // How can I pull the session info i.e. UserId here?
    var typedSessionUserId = base.SessionAs<MySession>().UserAuthId;    
}
```

If you don't have a custom session then you can access the built-in AuthUserSession:

```
var typedSessionUserId = base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>().UserAuthId;
```

Otherwise if you're using the dynamic session bag instead, you can access any custom variables you've added with:

```
var myUserId = base.Session["myUserId"];
```